# How to import a module in a C# JS runtime like V8.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, v8

In my C# code, I would like to execute javascript code that imports a module.

My C# code currently looks like this.

```cs
var code = """
import module from 'module';
"""
var engine = new V8Engine();
engine.Execute(code)
```

How can I achieve this.